# Naming convention for xibs 3.5inch and 4inch

Tags: ios, naming, convention

This is a simple question, i couldn't find anything but, is there a way to name your xib files so that ios knows to take one xib file over another depending on the version.
if you want to take a xib file for a class you name the xib file the same as the class
Ex:
ViewController.m
ViewController.xib

if you want to specify iphone or ipad you apply a tilde iphone/ipad
EX:
ViewController~iphone.xib
ViewController~ipad.xib

so restating the question, Is there a naming convention for ios 5.X and ios 6.X difference or no?

I ask this because ios 6.0 has some nice features regarding NSLayOutConstraints and attributed labels that i want to utilize but are not supported by one build. I ended up disabling auto layout and not using the attributed labels, just so i could have 1 code base and time was factor.

Granted I know i can do

```
if (mainWindow.frame.size.height == 568) {
   [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNib@"xibname"];
}
```

and i know i could make a class to take an NSString and create the proper string for the xib file depending on the screen size, but if i can fore go these methods and use something built in then that would be better.

Comment: You should just make you nibs grow with the size of the screen, that you will not need to for different nibs. You can [`autoresizingMask`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW6) of `UIView` for this so there is not need for the iOS6 only Autolayout.

Comment: what about the NSAttributedStrings that are supported in the ios 6.0 and not ios 5.X err that is to say not implemented so easily.... because my over all problem is i need text ot be bold, and 3rd party frameworks are discoloring the text which is un wated so i use some complicated code of taking the size of the text and resizing the area based on that size... but i get some off sets that are not wanted..... and simply all of that is fixed automatically in ios 6.0 XD

Answer (score 1):

```
+ (NSString *)getNibNameForName:(NSString *)name {
    if (IsiPhone4Inch) {
        NSString *possibleNibName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_iPhone4Inch", name];
        if ([[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:possibleNibName ofType:@"nib"] != nil) {
            return possibleNibName;
        }
    }

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:IS_IPAD ? @"%@_iPad":@"%@", name];
}
```

Comment: as ios will not pic the right nib file automatically...u can use any extension and can load nib using similar method shown above